# Drivers and software for Epson v600 scanner

Tags: drivers

I have read some of the answers here but have been unable to install the package for my scanner. This is the message I get when I try to open the .deb package. Help?

[image]

Comment: Install the `iscan-data` package, too.

Comment: @waltinator
I haven't been able to find that package. Do you have a link?

Comment: @waltinator
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You should probably look at `apt-cache search iscan`. The `iscan-data` package should be availabe from the same site that you got `iscan` from. Alternatively, look st `sane` (Scanner Access Now Easy): `apt-cache search sane`

Comment: @waltinator
I'm relatively new at linux, and while I use the terminal some, I'm still not quite familiar with it.
So, after running the first line you gave me, I got this:
duane@system76-pc:~$ apt-cache search iscan
exim4-daemon-heavy - Exim MTA (v4) daemon with extended features, including exiscan-acl
sa-exim - SpamAssassin filter for Exim

Now, I don't know what to do with it.
BTW, I appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].